# PGFPlots: pgfplotstableread with string column

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

This question is definitely a duplicate but I need some help with my scenario. I am really sorry that I couldn't figure it on my own.

I am using pgfplotstableread to read file and the contents of the file looks like,

```
Object  score
obj1    1
obj2    2
```

I initially used the following lines to read the dat file

```
\pgfplotstableread{images/densecap/segmentation_results.dat} \segresults
```

I got the error as follows:

```
Error: Could not parse input as a floating point number
```

Then after referring to some other answers from SE, I tried something like this,

```
 \pgfplotstableread[columns/Name/.style={string type}]{images/densecap/segmentation_results.dat} \segresults
```

But still getting the same error.

Could someone please help me with the syntax for using string as column in table file?

Comment: Reading shouldn't cause any problems, it's when you try to use that table that should cause errors. Try for example,`\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns/iObject/.style={string type}]\segresults}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Sure